# Why can't I include this .h?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

I wrote the includes:

```
#include "obj.h"
#include "textura.h"
```

Yet, I'm getting:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'obj.h': No such file or directory.
```

Why?

I tried previously to move the files to "header files", it didn't work, same error.

Comment: What .h. From where. How are you including it.

Comment: Since you have a folder for header files, shouldn't obj.h be in there?

Comment: A clue please! What is your include syntax? Where is the source file located? Where is the include file header?

Comment: So instead of posting the offending code and project settings, you choose to post a *picture* of your solution??? WTF

Comment: Why? -- because: "No such file or directory." Always listen to your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the directory path of obj.h (should be in file properties) and make sure that the directory that it's in is present in your project's default include directories.

Answer (score 2):

"Directory structure" that is shown does not actually exist. It is neither directory nor structure. Folders inside solution explorer are used only to visually group files, and for nothing more. The real question is where is obj.h located on disk. It must be in the same folder where .cpp is, which you want to compile. If it is not on the same folder then you:

- move obj.h in the same folder where .cpp is, or
- change #include directive to be a relative path beginning from .cpp and ending to obj.h, or
- set option in project that tells compiler where to find obj.h (Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories), or
- set option in Visual Studio that tells compiler where to find obj.h. This option is used for MSDN, or some other framework that you rely on heavily, and it should not be used for your own files.